# Why does this not count as an immutable borrow?

Tags: rust

I am reading [the official Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) and looking at listing 4-8 in Section 4.3.

The code looks like this:

```rust
fn first_word(s: &String) -> usize {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }

    s.len()
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello world");

    let word = first_word(&s);

    s.clear();
}
```

This line:

```rust
let word = first_word(&s);
```

seems to borrow an immutable reference to `s`. (This is where I guess I'm wrong; I just don't know why.)

In the next line, we mutate `s` by calling the `clear()` method.

I was expecting the compiler to throw:

```
cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

Why does this compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string `s` is immutably borrowed for the duration of the call to `first_word`. As soon as the control is returned to `main` after `first_word`, the string is not considered borrowed anymore and can be mutated as you have observed.

---

If `first_word` were to return a `&String` which you extended the lifetime of by assigning it to a variable, then you would see the error you expected. E.g.

```
fn first_word(s: &String) -> &String {
    &s
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello world");
    let word = first_word(&s);
    s.clear();
}
```

> cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

https://rust.godbolt.org/z/cMVdVf

In that case, adding an extra scope would fix that:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello world");

    {
        let word = first_word(&s);
    }

    s.clear();
}
```

Comment: But in that case, why does it fail to compile when we return a slice instead of an integer? (See the red listing on [this page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html), at ~75% scroll position.)

Comment: @DarshakParikh: it's the same principle as the code I've shown you that returns `-> String&`. The borrow survives outside of the scope of `first_word`, which means that `s` is still borrowed in `main` after we return to it.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. But why does it still survive once the borrower function has returned? What is so special with returning a reference instead of a primitive type?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. It's because we're assigning the returned reference to a variable and that makes the variable the new borrower.